# Android signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000023

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm new to android NDK, if I left out some information please let me know.
I modified a C++ program and built a .so library for my unity program. When I'm trying to run on android phone, I get this error. 
It happens when I click a button to get the pointer from the .so, then construct an raw image. The other functions are working fine.
I tested the .dll in 32bit unity, it was working properly.
I tried to use ndk-stack but I don't have a $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/ folder.
I'm totally stuck at this point. Pleeeeeease help!!!!!

```
E/CRASH: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000023
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
    Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/whyred/whyred:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.011/V10.3.1.0.OEIMIXM:user/release- 
keys'
    Revision: '0'
    pid: 25787, tid: 25931, name: UnityMain  >>> com.vasst.UltrasoundSimulator 
<<<
    r0 c71fe480  r1 ffffffff  r2 00000018  r3 c71fe450
    r4 c71fe38c  r5 e4d9d1b8  r6 00000000  r7 c71fe380
    r8 bc80f8c8  r9 c71fe480  sl 00000001  fp 00000001
    ip 00000000  sp c71fe378  lr b50972cf  pc b50974b6  cpsr e5389d10

    backtrace:
E/CRASH:   
    #00  pc 000724b6  /data/app/com.vasst.UltrasoundSimulator- 
VaTjisAN8985UPh_3TL_TQ==/lib/arm/libc++_shared.so (unw_get_proc_info+7)
    #01  pc 000722cb  /data/app/com.vasst.UltrasoundSimulator- 
VaTjisAN8985UPh_3TL_TQ==/lib/arm/libc++_shared.so 
(_Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData+18)
E/CRASH:   
    #02  pc 0006fd5f  /data/app/com.vasst.UltrasoundSimulator- 
VaTjisAN8985UPh_3TL_TQ==/lib/arm/libc++_shared.so 
(__cxxabiv1::scan_eh_tab(__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::scan_results&, 
_Unwind_Action, bool, _Unwind_Control_Block*, _Unwind_Context*)+106)
    #03  pc 0006fbe9  /data/app/com.vasst.UltrasoundSimulator- 
VaTjisAN8985UPh_3TL_TQ==/lib/arm/libc++_shared.so 
(__gxx_personality_v0+100)
    #04  pc 00b41808  /data/app/com.vasst.UltrasoundSimulator- 
VaTjisAN8985UPh_3TL_TQ==/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so 
(__gnu_Unwind_RaiseException+108)
    #05  pc 00b4234c  /data/app/com.vasst.UltrasoundSimulator- 
VaTjisAN8985UPh_3TL_TQ==/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so (_Unwind_RaiseException+20)



memory near r8:
bc80f8a8 c522b26c 00000000 c4f657d5 c4f6972d  l."......W..-...
bc80f8b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
bc80f8c8 43554e47 002b2b43 c4f65841 00000000  GNUCC++.AX......
bc80f8d8 b50ffac4 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
bc80f8e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
bc80f8f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
bc80f908 00000000 00000000 b512acf8 b51316fc  ................
bc80f918 00000000 00000000 e4764e10 3a8aeddd  .........Nv....:
bc80f928 ba222f21 39b219b8 00000000 00000000  !/"....9........
bc80f938 00000000 00000000 41211856 bef1ad70  ........V.!Ap...
bc80f948 bfecc916 bd005d8d beab1efb bd392c41  .....]......A,9.
bc80f958 bef1ad70 4134cba8 bfb2f9c7 3eab5fae  p.....4A....._.>
bc80f968 b987eee0 be31fa45 bfecc914 bfb2f9c7  ....E.1.........
bc80f978 3f3afeca bd1af60c 3d867509 3d03293e  ..:?.....u.=>).=
E/CRASH:     
bc80f988 bd005d90 3eab5fae bd1af60b 3c2353d1  .]..._.>.....S# 
<
bc80f998 3a15e540 bba390bc beab1efa b987ee00  @..:............
code around pc:
b5097494 200047e0 4802e000 8b04f85d bf00bdf0  .G. ...H].......
b50974a4 ffffe672 6a096801 b5d04708 460caf02  r....h.j.G.....F
b50974b4 6a4a6801 47904621 20006861 bf042900  .hJj!F.Gah. .)..
b50974c4 606bf24e 70fff6cf 0000bdd0 466fb580  N.k`...p......oF
b50974d4 6a896801 48014788 bf00bd80 ffffe674  .h.j.G.H....t...
b50974e4 466fb580 c000f8d0 c030f8dc 490347e0  ..oF......0..G.I
b50974f4 bf182800 46082100 bf00bd80 ffffe674  .(...!.F....t...
b5097504 466fb580 69526802 bd804790 6b926802  ..oF.hRi.G...h.k
b5097514 b5804710 6801466f 47886ac9 6801bd80  .G..oF.h.j.G...h
b5097524 47086bc9 47704770 20003910 0f13f111  .k.GpGpG.9. ....
E/CRASH:     
b5097534 2001bf88 30084770 b89cf000 f0003008  ... 
pG.0.....0..
b5097544 f021b8d5 f5a0001f fab07080 0940f080  ..!......p....@.
b5097554 30084770 b904f000 f0003008 b5d0b957  pG.0.....0..W...
b5097564 4604af02 0180f890 2000b108 4620bdd0  ...F....... .. F
b5097574 f9aaf000 d11b2801 21016820 46206b42  .....(.. h.!Bk F
b5097584 f8944790 28000180 f8d4d1ef b1700168  .G.....(....h.p.
code around lr:
E/CRASH:     
b50972ac 00011652 0001165d 000116d5 af02b5d0  
R...]...........
b50972bc 490ab08c 680c4479 910b6821 f000a901  ...IyD.h!h......
b50972cc 4601f8f0 29009803 2000bf18 6822990b  ...F...)... .."h
b50972dc bf041a51 bdd0b00c e964f7c2 000198c4  Q.........d.....
b50972ec af02b5d0 490ab08c 680c4479 910b6821  .......IyD.h!h..
b50972fc f000a901 4601f8d6 29009801 2000bf18  .......F...)... 
b509730c 6822990b bf041a51 bdd0b00c e94af7c2  .."hQ.........J.
E/CRASH:     
b509731c 00019890 b1126882 20014601 47704710  .....h...F. 
.GpG
b509732c 466fb580 f0004608 3801f8b9 2009bf18  ..oF.F.....8... 
b509733c 0000bd80 e8801fff e580d034 e580e038  ........4...8...
b509734c e580e03c e3a00000 e12fff1e ec800b20  <........./. ...
b509735c e12fff1e ec800b20 e12fff1e ecc00b20  ../. ...../. ...
b509736c e12fff1e af02b5d0 480e4604 23004a0e  ../......F.H.J.#
b509737c f8a44478 447a3048 f8843008 e9c4304a  xD..H0zD.0..J0..
b509738c f1040200 22400008 ea20f7c2 0050f104  ......@".. ...P.
b509739c 7199f44f e8b6f7c3 21004620 f92cf000  O..q.... F.!..,.

E/MessageQueue: IdleHandler threw exception
java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 
00000023
Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/whyred/whyred:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.011/V10.3.1.0.OEIMIXM:user/release- 
keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 25787, tid: 25931, name: UnityMain  >>> com.vasst.UltrasoundSimulator 
<<<
    r0 c71fe480  r1 ffffffff  r2 00000018  r3 c71fe450
    r4 c71fe38c  r5 e4d9d1b8  r6 00000000  r7 c71fe380
    r8 bc80f8c8  r9 c71fe480  sl 00000001  fp 00000001
    ip 00000000  sp c71fe378  lr b50972cf  pc b50974b6  cpsr e5389d10

at libc++_shared.unw_get_proc_info(unw_get_proc_info:7)
at  libc++_shared._Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData(_Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData:18)
at libc++_shared.__cxxabiv1::scan_eh_tab(__cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::scan_results&, _Unwind_Action, bool, _Unwind_Control_Block*, _Unwind_Context*)(scan_eh_tab:106)
at libc++_shared.__gxx_personality_v0(__gxx_personality_v0:100)
at libil2cpp.__gnu_Unwind_RaiseException(__gnu_Unwind_RaiseException:108)
at libil2cpp._Unwind_RaiseException(_Unwind_RaiseException:20)
```